# Performing an operation by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data

Here is my data

```
resolution <- c(1:9)
country <- c("Afg", "Afg", "Afg", "Bel", "Bel", "Bel", "Chi", "Chi", "Chi")
year <- c(2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017)
vote <- c(1,0,0.5,1,1,0,0,1.5,1)
df <- cbind.data.frame(country, year, resolution, vote)
```

I want to calculate a new variable called coincidence which performs the following algebraic operation for each country:

```
coincidence(country) = number of 1s times 1 + number of 0.5s times 0.5
coincidence(afg) = ((1*1) + (1*0.5)) = 1.5
```

i.e., it counts the number of 1s and 0.5s for all years per country, and then sums them. As I have one 1 and one 0.5 for Afghanistan, coincidence should be 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 (the value of coincidence should be the same for all years per country).

Comment: Tidyverse's [`group_by()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) is one way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(country) %>% mutate(coincidence = sum(vote==1) + sum(vote == 0.5) *0.5)
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   country [3]
  country  year resolution  vote coincidence
  <chr>   <dbl>      <int> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Afg      2015          1   1           1.5
2 Afg      2015          2   0           1.5
3 Afg      2015          3   0.5         1.5
4 Bel      2016          4   1           2  
5 Bel      2016          5   1           2  
6 Bel      2016          6   0           2  
7 Chi      2017          7   0           1  
8 Chi      2017          8   1.5         1  
9 Chi      2017          9   1           1
```